# Jboss @QueryParam and String []

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, annotations

Hi i have a weird thing observed while hitting the URL. My colleague asked me to hit the URL as

```
https://yyyy.com/echo?modelID={aaa1,bbb2}
```

to pass input values for service as an array. But the below logic

```
@QueryParam ("modelID") String[] modelID
```

is accepting only the format as

```
URL: https://xxxx.com/echo?modelID=aaa1&modelID=bbb2
```

Help required to understand this and how to change the logic to accept the input as

```
https://yyyy.com/echo?modelID={aaa1,bbb2}
```

Comment: Show us the code that wires this up.

Comment: Looks like a non standard way of dealing with arrays.  I think you need to set the type of modelID to String and do the array encoding yourself

Comment: You could create a custom type and then add your own [StringConverter](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/StringConverter.html)

Comment: @JasonSperske: How can i ancode array ? Can you help me out i have no Idea.

Comment: @MattBall: This is just an interface designed and the Method is PUT. Using JBOSS RESTServices